# How to partition a component's generic props and strongly type the results

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-functional-component, react-typescript

i'm trying to partition a custom type back into it's individual elements:

`type CustomType<T extends React.ElementType> = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T> & { aBunchOfProps: string; }`

code looks like following:

```
const partitionProps = <T extends React.ElementType>(
  props: CustomType<T>
): {
  customProps: { aBunchOfProps: string }, // named type
  componentProps: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>
} => {
  const {
    aBunchOfProps,
    ...componentProps
  } = props;

  const customProps = { aBunchOfProps };

  return { customProps, componentProps };
} // Error! componentProps: Omit<CustomType<T>, { aBunchOfProps }> is 
  // not assignable to type ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>
```

which is weird because I'm able to assert type equality

```
type Equals<T, U> = T extends U ? (U extends T : true : false) : false;

type AreTheyEqual<T extends React.ElementType> = Equals<
  Omit<CustomType<T>, { aBunchOfProps: string }>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>
>;
type UsingDiv = AreTheyEqual<'div'>; // true
type UsingA = AreTheyEqual<'a'>; // true
type UsingIFrame = AreTheyEqual<'iframe'>; //true
```

there should be maybe some conditional type to assert type equality in the partition function, but I can't quite figure it out

```
type AssertEquality<T extends React.ElementType> = Equals<T1, T2> extends true ? React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T> : never;
```

but that doesn't quite work either.

Any ideas?

---

Edit 11/1/21: See [this typescript playground for a reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAMolYASWANqyjoAvHADeKAEIBXAHa4AFgHkCABWJhUALjioYUYLIDmNOAF96zVnADC0vSQAqLLAB5HcLAA8YWWQBN0bDwYADoAUT4sED8YZ1YAPjhRThjeASwhOAAyTCowmxJIWVj1CE0AdWAYBQhpGGwCdwT6OlwIWT04MGRYauAOss1kuHdPHz9AvJCIqJjZOJcEgAo6OG6NbVt7GCcXZroASh0xNbhcHZIhrYlkGXllNU2dPQNjcwAaOAB6b7hZZAxfxwKxYM7tcAdUrPab4UKFSElBbXKo1OoNLBNRwJOhmZJJU7rdqdeCE9ZSOSKFTXD5ndahBkQ4rQ8qoM540RgTatIkdLoXBwga4jW73KlPVnmHlwSgwaRQWTic6XIWbL5MqHIzZS3E-P7hKDEKAAQnORU1MGuOiUIGqrjsgvibmxX1FlMewrMSWA6DOv3%20EHgaFQwCMAIARlEQRAQS5bOakZbNqjavVGs0gA). We're able to force cast the return type as `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>` but it still leaves the function and exists inside of calling components as `any`.

Comment: Could you create a Typescript playground that demonstrates the whole problem?

Comment: Please keep in mind that your implementation of `Equal` should be written as here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650

Comment: @captain-yossarian The implementation of the `Equals` type that is in that comment is wrong for my particular use case, unfortunately.

They say that their implementation isn't able to handle case `H`, which is an object union.

My implementation of `Equals` is able to handle that case, which is the case that I'm testing for here. If I were to use the given implementation, it would give me false negatives.

Comment: @zprobinson please provide reproducible example in ts playground

Comment: There is a typescript playground that demonstrates the error. We're able to cast it, but calling code will not be able to tell what that `componentProps` is typed as. It will still be read as `any`

Comment: @zprobinson how do you want to call this function?

Comment: `const { customProps, componentProps } = partitionProps(props);`. I think based on what you responded below, the generic parameter must be passed to the function in order for it to correctly type the `componentProps`. It should be called like this instead: `const { customProps, componentProps } = partitionProps<"div">(props);` Otherwise, since `React.ElementType<P = any>`, `componentProps` will be typed as `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using generic inside the function

```js
const partitionProps = <T extends React.ElementType>(
  props: CustomType<T>
): { /** ....some code */ }
```

`T` is like black box, it will be known only during the call of a function, whereas comparison of :

```js
type UsingDiv = AreTheyEqual<'div'>; // true
type UsingA = AreTheyEqual<'a'>; // true
type UsingIFrame = AreTheyEqual<'iframe'>; //true
```

is much easier to to because generic parameter of `AreTheyEqual` is known at compile time : `div`, `a`, `iframe`.

Imagine, we don't have a generic type in our function:

```js
const partitionProps = (
    props: SomeHelpers & ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'a'>
  ): {
    customProps: { aBunchOfProps: string },
    componentProps: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'a'>
  } => {
  const {
    aBunchOfProps,
    ...componentProps
  } = props;
  const customProps = { aBunchOfProps };

  return { customProps, componentProps };
}
```

There are no errors, because TS is able to infer exact type of `componentProps`.

Once you have provided `T`, TS is no more sure about type equality.
Since, it is unsafe to return

```js
{
    customProps: { aBunchOfProps: string },
    componentProps: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>
  }
```

However, you can loose the strict behavior. You can overload your function. Overloadings are bivariant.

```js
type SomeHelpers = { aBunchOfProps: string };

type CustomType<T extends React.ElementType> = SomeHelpers &
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>;

function partitionProps<T extends React.ElementType<{ tag: number }>>(
  props: CustomType<T>
): {
  customProps: { aBunchOfProps: string }; // named type
  componentProps: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>;
};
function partitionProps<T extends React.ElementType>(props: CustomType<T>) {
  const { aBunchOfProps, ...componentProps } = props;

  const customProps = { aBunchOfProps };

  return { customProps, componentProps };
}

const result = partitionProps({
  aBunchOfProps: 'sdf',
  tag: 42
});
```

Please keep in mind that you also should provide a generic argument to `React.ElementType` because if you don't generic parameter will be `any`.
See `ElementType` signature:

```js
 type ElementType<P = any> =
        {
            [K in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]: P extends JSX.IntrinsicElements[K] ? K : never
        }[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements] |
        ComponentType<P>;
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! I think that ended up being the solution. If the function is called like:

`const { customProps, componentProps } = partitionProps<"div">(props)`

it types correctly. The generic parameter must be passed.

The reason is exactly why you say. I completely missed the default generic parameter of ElementType being set to any.

Comment: @zprobinson I missed `ElementType` generic parameter at the beginning too